# "Access Denied" error whilst programmatically activating a feature in SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am new to SharePoint so I am following some Microsoft Learning Guides. One exercise is to create a feature reciever to modify the Web.Config file. 
I detect the feature being activated or deactivated and call the following routine with the appropriate flag.

```
void setProliferationFlag(bool status)
{
    SPWebApplication webApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri("http://SharePoint"));
try
{
    SPWebConfigModification mySetting = null;
    if (status)
    {
    mySetting = new SPWebConfigModification();
    mySetting.Path = "configuration/appSettings";
    mySetting.Name = "add [@key='preventProliferation'] [@value='1']";
    mySetting.Sequence = 0;
    mySetting.Owner = "Lab05Owner";
    mySetting.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;
    mySetting.Value = "<add key='preventProliferation' value='1' />";
    webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(mySetting);
}
else
{
    foreach (SPWebConfigModification modification in 
        webApp.WebConfigModifications)
    {
        if (modification.Owner == "Lab05Owner")
        {
            modification.Value = "<add key='preventProliferation' value='0' />";
        }
    }
}
    webApp.Update();
    webApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
}
catch
{ 
}
```

The event receivers work fine. When I activate the feature this code is run, but when it reaches the "webApp.Update()" line it fails with an "Access Denied" error. No other detils on the error. I am not sure to what the access is denied.
I am running in my development environment on my laptop. This is a Sharepoint Server 2010 installation on Window 7.

Regards Tim

Comment: first of all: get a decent stacktrace --> change the web.config by setting customerrors to ` <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />` en callstack to `CallStack="true"`. From which account are you activating the feature? More important; which rights does this account have..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you will need administrative access. Look at the [`SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx) which allows you to execute such actions within the system account's security context.

You will have to run the whole code elevated, that is including opening the `SPWebApplication` object. You method will then look like this:

```
void SetProliferationFlag(…)
{
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
    {
        // … your code goes here …
    });
}
```

---

Please also note, it's a very bad practice to have empty `catch` clauses in your code. Do always handle *all* exceptions, at least by logging them and rethrowing.

Comment: thanks,yeah the code is copied stright from the microsoft training material. WIll give this a try.